# Jenkins - Publishing html table on build summary page

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I want to publish html table on build summary page.
Something like this
[image]
HTML publisher allows only publish a link to the report while postBuild makes not supporting html tables and makes me to add imagem so those plugins doesnt do the job.

Which plugin can do the job?

Comment: You are not providing enough information in you question. Why do the mentioned plugins not work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First there is summary report plug in
https://plugins.jenkins.io/summary_report/

Second I used markup.html to publish a summary table, for example:

```
def writer = new StringWriter()  // html is written here by markup builder
    def markup = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(writer)  // the builder
    
    markup.html{
        markup.table(class:"table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed") {
        markup.thead{
            markup.tr {
                    markup.th(title:"Field #1", "task name")
                    markup.th(title:"Field #2", "status")
                    markup.th(title:"Field #3", "link")
            } // tr
        } // thead
        markup.tbody{
            markup.tr{
                    markup.td(align:"right","Name")
                    markup.td(align:"right","RESULT")
                    markup.td(align:"right","DATA")
            } // tr
        } //tbody
    } // table
   }
   manager.createSummary("accept.png").appendText(writer.toString(), false, false, false, "green")
```

Answer (score 0):

The Badge plugin allows you to do this via a "Build Summary", though I never really tried to put a complex dataset like an html table in it:
https://github.com/jenkinsci/badge-plugin#createsummary